# Remove horizontal dividers for smaller screens (CSS grid)

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

**Problem faced:** The CSS grid applied in my app has horizontal gaps between cells. These horizontal gaps appear when the screen is toggled in mobile mode as seen here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/css-grid-divider-issue-yvdvut?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). This problem is prominent in smaller screens (mobile) and when the cells have the same background colour as shown in the CodeSandbox.

**How to reproduce the problem I'm facing:** To see the problem in the CodeSandbox, please select the icon "Open preview in new window" in the Sandbox. In the new browser, right click and choose "Inspect" and go to mobile screens. **OR** If you're able to go into editing mode in the Sandbox, please select "Toggle Responsive View" (2nd icon from right of the url bar under "Browser" tab).

**What I require:** If the code above can be modified to eliminate these gaps or a code snippet that solves the problem can be shown, that would be greatly appreciated.

[image: this is how the problem looks like]

Comment: have you tried using media querry?

Comment: I have not, if you have any working code that effectively resolves this problem using media query please feel free to share too

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a kind of edge effect, where the system is struggling to match CSS pixels to screen pixels (there can be several screen pixels to one CSS pixel on modern screens).

You aren't seeing whole CSS pixel gaps, but a screen pixel or so 'left behind' from the calculation.

Here's a plain CSS/HTML example with a workaround, if a bit hacky. Adding a couple of CSS pixels to the height of the grid items and positioning them 1px up so you are sure to get some overlap:

```css
.largearea {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 8fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "firstarea" "secondarea" "thirdarea" "fourtharea";
}

.largearea * {
  background-color: black;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.firstarea {
  grid-area: firstarea;
}

.secondarea {
  grid-area: secondarea;
}

.thirdarea {
  grid-area: thirdarea;
}

.fourtharea {
  grid-area: fourtharea;
}
```

```html
<div class="largearea">
  <div class="firstarea"></div>
  <div class="secondarea"></div>
  <div class="thirdarea"></div>
  <div class="fourtharea"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've tried implementing this code but it still does not resolve the problem. When I try this method, I can still see the dividers and when I implement this with components, the interface looks quite jumbled up for the mobile screens

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried for this as it works for plain css/HTML (at least in the places I’ve had to use it).

Comment: [CodeSandbox link: with height and transformation code](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-grid-divider-issue-yvdvut?from-embed=&file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=561&resolutionHeight=675) 

the changes have been made to styles.css in order to see the changes (if you're not in editing mode), you might have to select the icon "Open preview in new window" in the Sandbox. In the new browser, right click and choose "Inspect" and go to mobile screens.

Comment: Thanks, that's very strange. I've looked at your sandbox which now has the height 100% + 2px in it. I do not see any lines when going to mobile view but if I replace that with height: 100% I do see the lines returning. I'm on Windows10 Edge/Chrome. What system/browser are you on?

Comment: I'm currently on macos/Chrome

Comment: Sorry I can't get to a MacOS machine at the moment so cannot test further.